# calculation using shift and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, shift

I would like to calculate a new column "change". 
The value of the new column shall be calculated as follows: 
X / Z (one cell above)
--> first row would be empty.
--> second row would be 1 / 6 = 0,16
-> second row would be 5 / 10 = 0,5 ...and so on..

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b','b'],
                    'Z': [6,10,8, 6, 6,15],
                     'X': [2,1,5, 2, 3,20]})
var =  df.columns[1]
```

[image: df]

In the forum I found this:
 `df['change'] = df['X'] / df[var].shift(1)`
It works fine. But I needed to insert a "groupby" argument and cant get it to work.
I tried this:
`df['change'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['X'] / x[var].shift(1))`
But I get an error:
*"incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"*

I am afraid I have not fully understood this lambda function.
Any ideas how to get that right?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just divide `X` column by shifted groups:

```
df["change"] = df["X"] / df.groupby("id")["Z"].shift(1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  id   Z   X    change
0  a   6   2       NaN
1  a  10   1  0.166667
2  a   8   5  0.500000
3  b   6   2       NaN
4  b   6   3  0.500000
5  b  15  20  3.333333
```

Comment: easy as that, great, thank you very much!